# Is there a closed form expression that gives, for a integer n, the number of the first row of pascal triangle that has some entries higher than n?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm interested in finding a closed formula for the index of the first row of the triangle that contains an integer greater than $n$.

Alternatively:

- What is the dimension of the smallest hypercube that has a "middle" antichain bigger than $n$?
- What is the smallest number of elements that a set needs so that a Sperner family over this set is bigger than $n$?
- Given an integer $n$, find the smallest $d$ such that $\binom{d}{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}\geq n$.

I know the size of a Sperner family is bounded by $\binom{d}{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}$ with $d$ the size of the ground set. I cannot work the other way around to find a $d$ such that $\binom{d}{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}$ is bigger than $n$.

Comment: A closed form is hopeless but precise asymptotics are known for ${d \choose d/2}$ via Stirling's formula.

Comment: Why is it hopeless?